# Animal Reserve Method

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to work on an Animal Reserve method within the Driver class. It is supposed to prompt the user to enter an animal type, which would be either monkey or dog. After that it should prompt user to enter country the animal is from. Then it should search through the current list and then change the reserved status of that animal from false to true. Whenever I run the program, I get a menu as I should. Then I press 3 to call the reserveAnimal method. Instead of prompting and letting the user enter animal type, it just skips that and directly prints error message, saying "Type not found". How can I fix this? Here is my current code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Driver {
private static ArrayList<Dog> dogList = new ArrayList<Dog>();
private static ArrayList<Monkey> monkeyList = new ArrayList<Monkey>();
// Instance variables (if needed)

public static void main(String[] args) {


    initializeDogList();
    initializeMonkeyList();

    // Creates a scanner class object
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    char option;
    // Displays the menu in loop until the user enters the exit option
    do
    {
        displayMenu();
        option=input.next().charAt(0);
        // If user input is 1, intakeNewDog method is called
        if(option=='1') {
            
            intakeNewDog(input);
        }
        // If the option is 2, the intakeNewMonkey method is called
        else if(option=='2') {
            
            intakeNewMonkey(input);
        }
        // If the option is 3, the reserveAnimal method is called
        else if(option=='3') {
        
            reserveAnimal(input);
        }
        // If the option is 4, the printAnimals method is called to print dog list
        else if(option=='4') {
            
            printAnimals();
        }
        // If the option is 5, the printAnimals method is called to print monkey list
        else if(option=='5') {
            
            printAnimals();
        }
        // If the option is 6, the printAnimals method is called to print all available 
        animals
        else if(option=='6') {
            
            printAnimals();
        }
        // If the option is q, exit message prints and application stops running
        else if(option=='q') {
            
            System.out.print("You have exited the application.");
            break;
        }
        else {
            System.out.print("You have entered an invalid input.");
        }
        }while (option != 'q');
    // For the project submission you must also include input validation
    // and appropriate feedback to the user.
    // Hint: create a Scanner and pass it to the necessary
    // methods 
    // Hint: Menu options 4, 5, and 6 should all connect to the printAnimals() method.

  }

// This method prints the menu options
public static void displayMenu() {
    System.out.println("\n\n");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\tRescue Animal System Menu");
    System.out.println("[1] Intake a new dog");
    System.out.println("[2] Intake a new monkey");
    System.out.println("[3] Reserve an animal");
    System.out.println("[4] Print a list of all dogs");
    System.out.println("[5] Print a list of all monkeys");
    System.out.println("[6] Print a list of all animals that are not reserved");
    System.out.println("[q] Quit application");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Enter a menu selection");
}


// Adds dogs to a list for testing
public static void initializeDogList() {
    Dog dog1 = new Dog("Spot", "German Shepherd", "male", "1", "25.6", "05-12-2019", "United States", "intake", false, "United States");
    Dog dog2 = new Dog("Rex", "Great Dane", "male", "3", "35.2", "02-03-2020", "United States", "Phase I", false, "United States");
    Dog dog3 = new Dog("Bella", "Chihuahua", "female", "4", "25.6", "12-12-2019", "Canada", "in service", true, "Canada");

    dogList.add(dog1);
    dogList.add(dog2);
    dogList.add(dog3);
}


// Adds monkeys to a list for testing
//Optional for testing
public static void initializeMonkeyList() {
    Monkey monkey1 = new Monkey("Albert", "male", "8", "9.5", "06-12-2019", "Costa Rica", "in service", false, "United States", "17.6", "18.4", "18.1", "Capuchin");
    Monkey monkey2 = new Monkey("Ada", "female", "6", "1.2", "04-18-2020", "Brazil", "Phase 4", true, "Canada", "13.2", "10.1", "9.9", "Tamarin");
    Monkey monkey3 = new Monkey("Galileo", "male", "7", "7.8", "11-22-2019", "Congo", "Phase 3", false, "United States", "26.2", "20.3", "21.2", "Guenon");
    
    monkeyList.add(monkey1);
    monkeyList.add(monkey2);
    monkeyList.add(monkey3);

}


// Complete the intakeNewDog method
// The input validation to check that the dog is not already in the list
// is done for you
public static void intakeNewDog(Scanner scanner) {
    scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What is the dog's name?");
    String name = scanner.nextLine();
    for(Dog dog: dogList) {
        if(dog.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
            System.out.println("\n\nThis dog is already in our system\n\n");
            return; //returns to menu
        }
    }

    // Add the code to instantiate a new dog and add it to the appropriate list
    System.out.println("What is the dog's breed?");
    String breed = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What is the dog's gender?");
    String gender = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What is the dog's age?");
    String age = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What is the dog's weight?");
    String weight = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("When was this dog acquired?");
    String acquisitionDate = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Which country was this dog acquired?");
    String acquisitionCountry = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What is the dog's training status?");
    String trainingStatus = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Is this dog reserved?");
    boolean reserved = scanner.nextBoolean();
    scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Which country is the dog in service?");
    String inServiceCountry = scanner.nextLine();
    
    Dog dog4 = new Dog(name, breed, gender, age, weight, acquisitionDate, acquisitionCountry, trainingStatus, reserved, inServiceCountry);
    dogList.add(dog4);
    System.out.println("Your entry has been added to the dog list.");
}


    // Complete intakeNewMonkey
//Instantiate and add the new monkey to the appropriate list
    // For the project submission you must also  validate the input
// to make sure the monkey doesn't already exist and the species type is allowed
    public static void intakeNewMonkey(Scanner scanner) {
        scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is the monkey's name?");
        String name = scanner.nextLine();
        for(Monkey monkey: monkeyList) {
            if(monkey.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                System.out.println("\n\nThis monkey is already in our system\n\n");
                return; //returns to menu
            }
        }
        System.out.println("What is the monkey's gender?");
        String gender = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is the monkey's age?");
        String age = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is the monkey's weight?");
        String weight = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("When was this monkey acquired?");
        String acquisitionDate = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Which country was this monkey acquired?");
        String acquisitionCountry = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is the monkey's training status?");
        String trainingStatus = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Is this monkey reserved?");
        boolean reserved = scanner.nextBoolean();
        scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Which country is the monkey in service?");
        String inServiceCountry = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("How long is the monkey's tail?");
        String tailLength = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is the monkey's height?");
        String height = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is the monkey's body length?");
        String bodyLength = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What species is the monkey?");
        String species = scanner.nextLine();
        
        Monkey monkey4 = new Monkey(name, gender, age, weight, acquisitionDate, 
        acquisitionCountry, trainingStatus, reserved, inServiceCountry, tailLength, height, 
        bodyLength, species);
        monkeyList.add(monkey4);
        System.out.print("Your entry has been added to the monkey list.");
    }

    // Complete reserveAnimal
    // You will need to find the animal by animal type and in service country
    public static void reserveAnimal(Scanner scanner) {
        System.out.println("Enter animal type: ");
        String animalType = scanner.nextLine();
        if (animalType.equalsIgnoreCase("Monkey")) {
            System.out.println("Enter the monkey's country of acquisiton: ");
            String country = scanner.nextLine();
            for(Monkey obj: monkeyList) {
                if(obj.getAcquisitionLocation().equalsIgnoreCase(country)) {
                    obj.setReserved(true);
                    return;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("The monkey entered is not in the list");
        }
        else if (animalType.equalsIgnoreCase("Dog")) {
                System.out.println("Enter the dog's country of acquisition: ");
                String country = scanner.nextLine();
                for(Dog obj: dogList){
                if(obj.getAcquisitionLocation().equalsIgnoreCase(country)){
                    obj.setReserved(true);
                    return;
                }

            }
            System.out.println("The dog entered is not in the list");
            }  else {
            System.out.println("Type not found");
            }
    
    }

    // Complete printAnimals
    // Include the animal name, status, acquisition country and if the animal is reserved.
// Remember that this method connects to three different menu items.
    // The printAnimals() method has three different outputs
    // based on the listType parameter
    // dog - prints the list of dogs
    // monkey - prints the list of monkeys
    // available - prints a combined list of all animals that are
    // fully trained ("in service") but not reserved 
// Remember that you only have to fully implement ONE of these lists. 
// The other lists can have a print statement saying "This option needs to be implemented".
// To score "exemplary" you must correctly implement the "available" list.
    public static void printAnimals() {
        System.out.println("The method printAnimals needs to be implemented");

    }
 }
```

Comment: Please have a look at how to write a [MCVE]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to add `scanner.nextLine();` as the first line in `reserveAnimal` method.